# Old values from multiple select in Laravel 10 and select2

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

In my Laravel project, I am using select2, in order to have a simple filter system. One of the things I want to do is keep the old values in the input after filtering (and keep them selected in the backend). I've tried to do it a few ways, but Laravel doesn't support that. I am a newbie to Laravel, so most of them were beginner tries and mistakes.

The code I have, I can best explain textually, but for the **sake** of it I did leave the code down below as well.

**`Views/product-search.blade.php`**

Has a select multiple, which has 3 functions attached to it.

1: if the form is submitted → remove the name attribute from the select element

2: `onchange` → append the database-id of the selected option to a hidden input

3: `onwindowload` → set the input back to '-- Select Certificates --'

**I think what I want to do is** add an option to the third function, in the placeholder, that sets the selected values to the placeholder field.

**But** I have another view as well, a component :

**`views/component/select2.blade.php`**

This is a reusable component, so IDs are dynamic but persistent throughout the file.

Here it gets confusing to me, because there is an `@if(!$multiple)`, so if multiple is false. In other words, it doesn't have the multiple property, right?

Then this file has a script part as well, which has 2 main functions that are being used. It also has a third one, but that is to `$.focus()`. This script other than that speaks for itself.

**Now for the code below:**

**`views/product-search.blade.php`**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <label for="certificates" class="form-label">Certificates</label>
  <select id="certificates" class="multiple-select select2-theme select2-transparent" multiple="multiple"></select>

  <input type="hidden" name="product_certificates" id="product_certificates" />

  <p class="mb-0">
    <small>
      <i class="bx bx-info-circle gses-primary"></i>
      <em>Because of the big amount of certificates, this can require 15+ seconds loading time</em>
    </small>
  </p>
</div>

{{-- And then some @pushonce script --}}

$('#product_search_form').submit(function () {
  $('input[name="certificates"]').remove();
});

// If the input changes, edit the certificate accordingly
$('#certificates').change(function () {
  let certificates = '';
  let selected_certificates = $(this).children().length;

  $(this).children().each(function (i, el) {
    certificates += $(el).val();

    if (i !== (selected_certificates - 1))
      certificates += ',';
    });

  $('#product_certificates').val(certificates);
});

// Set the input to the default.
// TODO: Modify the placeholder to include the old selected and dis-include them from the search
  $('#certificates').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap-5',
    width: $(this).hasClass('w-100') ? '100%' : 'style',
    placeholder: '-- Select Certificates --',
    allowClear: Boolean($(this).data('allow-clear')),
    ajax: {
      url: 'autocomplete/product-exemptions',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          term: params.term || '',
          page: params.page || 1
        }
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });
});
```

**views/component/select2.blade.php**

```
<select
  name="{{ $name }}"
  id="{{ $id }}"
  class="{{ $class }}{{ ( ! is_null($theme) ? ' select2-theme select2-'.$theme : '' ) }}"
  {{ ( $multiple ?? 'multiple="multiple"' ) }}
  data-width="{{ $width }}"
  {{$attributes}}
>
  @isset ($placeholder)
    @if (!$multiple)
      <option value="{{ $placeholderValue }}" disabled selected>
        {{ $placeholder }}
      </option>
    @endif
  @endisset
</select>

@push('push-script')
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      let placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');

      if ('{{ $placeholder }}' !== '' && '{{ $multiple }}' === 'multiple') {
         placeholder = '{{ $placeholder }}';
      }

      $('select[name="{{ $name }}"]').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap-5',
        width: $(this).data('width') ? $(this).data('width') : $(this).hasClass('w-100') ? '100%' : 'style',
        placeholder: placeholder,
        allowClear: Boolean($(this).data('allow-clear')),
        ajax: {
          url: '{{ $url }}',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
            return {
              term: params.term || '',
              page: params.page || 1
            }
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
@endpush
```

And for my final question to be clear: How can I add multiple old selected values to the correct script(s) and how do I keep them from being allowed to be filtered again (I.E. after you press search you keep certificate1 as a selected and in the list you can't select it again)

I hope this explanation and code made it clear and answerable. Thanks!

I've tried a few things, but I have too limited knowledge of select2 and not much knowledge of Laravel to combine these 2 into an old multiple select. Because of some complications with how we "inject" everything, other posts also did not seem to help.